# Higher-ranked polymorphism without explicit application or subtyping?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, functional-programming, type-checking, polymorphisms

So, I'm familiar with two main strategies of having higher-ranked polymorphism in a language:

- System-F style polymorphism, where functions are explicitly typed, and instantiation happens explicitly though type application. These systems can be impredicative.
- Subtyping-based polymorphism, where a polymorphic type is a subtype of all of its instantiations. To have decidable subtyping, polymorphism must be predicative. [This paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~joshuad/papers/bidir/) provides an example of such a system.

However, some languages, like Haskell, have impredicative higher-ranked polymorphism without explicit type applications.

How is this possible? How can type-checking "know" when to instantiate a type without an explicit instantiation or cast, and without a notion of subtyping?

Or, is typechecking even decidable in such a system? Is this a case where language like Haskell implement something undecidable that happens to work for most peoples' use cases.

**EDIT:**

To be clear, I'm interested in the *uses*, not definitions, of polymorphically-typed values.

For example, suppose we have:

```
f : forall a . a -> a
g : (forall a . a -> a) -> Int
val = (g f, f True, f 'a')
```

How can we know that we need to instantiate `f` when it's applied, but not when it's given as an argument?

Or, to separate ourselves from function types:

```
f : forall a . a
g : (forall a . a) -> Int
val = (g f, f && True, f + 0)
```

Here, we can't even distinguish the use of `f` as applying it versus passing it: it's instantiated when passed as an argument to `&&` and `+`, but not `g`.

How can a theoretical system distinguish these two cases without a magical "you can convert any polymorphic type to its instance" rule? Or with a rule like that, can we know when to apply it, to keep decidability?

Comment: Haskell will never infer a polytype for a type variable, unless it's explicitly provided by the user. E.g. `\f -> (f True, f 'a')` won't type check, even if it can be assigned the type `(forall t. t->t) -> (Bool, Char)`

Comment: @chi I'm interested in the *uses*, not definitions, of polymorphic values, see my edit for an example of what I mean. Sorry if this wasn't clear at first.

Comment: There should be some Simon Peyton-Jones paper which explains the inference algorithm (I can't point which one, though). But probably the inference engine can see that `g` expects a polytype, and prevents the instantiation of `f`.

Comment: @chi probably https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/practical-type-inference-for-arbitrary-rank-types/ and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/outsideinx-modular-type-inference-with-local-assumptions/

Answer (score 7):

The Dunfield & Krishnaswami paper's introduction refers to [Practical type inference for arbitrary-rank types](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/practical-type-inference-for-arbitrary-rank-types/)

> As can be seen, it scales well to advanced type systems; moreover,
>   it is easy to implement, and yields relatively high-quality error messages
>   (Peyton Jones et al. 2007)

In System F-ish approach there is also a "subtyping" relation. See section 3.3 Subsumption.

---

I'd also *emphasize* that Haskell doesn't have impredicative types (or inference for them). See: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/ghc-devs/2016-September/012940.html for pointers.

> - You can write a polytype in a visible type argument; eg.  f @(forall a. a->a)
> - You can write a polytype as an argument of a type in a signature  e.g.  f :: [forall a. a->a] -> Int
>
>   And that’s all.  A unification variable STILL CANNOT be unified with a polytype.  The only way you can call a polymorphic function at a polytype is to use Visible Type Application.
>
> In short, if you call a function at a polytype, you must use VTA.  Simple, easy, predictable; and doubtless annoying.  But possible.

I.e. `id id` will always be elaborated as

```
forall a. id @(a -> a) (id @a)
```

*not*

```
id @(forall a. a -> a) id
```

Yet, you can write the latter explictly, if you enable `ImpredicativeTypes`.

Answer (score 3):

To check the application of a function like `g : (forall a. a -> a) -> Int` to `f`, we need to check that `f : forall a. a -> a`.

Instead of matching quantifiers (which would be quite brittle), we introduce a fresh, rigid (i.e., non-unifiable) variable, say `a1`, and we need to check that `f : a1 -> a1`, and now we can carry on as usual, instantiating `f` at `a1` (modulo additional checks to ensure that `a1` does not escape its scope).

The actual algorithm is detailed in the paper phadej linked.

> Or, is typechecking even decidable in such a system? Is this a case where language like Haskell implement something undecidable that happens to work for most peoples' use cases.

The general problem of *type inference* in the presence of higher-ranked polymorphism remains undecidable. However, with full type annotations it becomes a (mostly?) decidable *type checking* problem. GHC's algorithm must thus be incomplete, but tries to cover as much ground as it can in the middle of these two situations, with the help of a few sparse type annotations.